# When exporting from ORGMODE: user-error: Unable to resolve link: "pdf:/Users/<USER>/Documents/Google Drive/randomPDF.pdf"

Tags: emacs, export

I am getting this error when I export from an OrgMode buffer by executing `C-c C-e t` (export as  plain text, any of the suboptions `A L U a l u`). This does not happen always, so it most only happen with certain buffers, so there must be something inherent in them:

```
user-error: Unable to resolve link: "pdf:/Users/<USER>/Documents/Google Drive/randomPDF.pdf"
```

Comment: There is no `pdf` link type: your link should probably look like `file:/Users/<USER>/Documents/Google Drive/randomPDF.pdf` - of course, you should also make sure that the file exists.

Comment: Is there a way to override this? I have plenty of non-located in disk PDFs, I just need them in the text even if they don't exist on disk.

Comment: If you can view them with a PDF viewer, then you can link to them with a `file:` link. This is not so much Org mode as it is about accessing Google Drive I think.